# How to pass AngularJS Response to window.url

Tags: angularjs, query-string

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,$http){

$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '../api/CreateOrder',
                data: Object.toparams(myobject),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                window.location.href = "checkout.html?OrderId=" + response.data;


            }, function errorCallback(response) {

                alert("Error. while updating user Try Again!");

            });

});
```

Here is my code , I am receiving response from http GET , How to transfer the response data which has OrderId to window.location.href as Parameter?

Comment: can you post an example of `response.data`?

Comment: In repsonse I get an array [{OrderId : 25 }]

Comment: You'll have to access the property OrderId within your response.data. If what you say is correct, it should be response.data[0].OrderId 

This takes the first object from the responsedata array. You should ofcourse check if there is any item in the response.data.

Comment: I tried that but getting URL Like this : 
http://localhost:56861/public/checkout.html?OrderId=[object%20Object]

If i pass response.data in window.location.href = "checkout.html?OrderId ="+response.data

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that `response.data` is `[{OrderId : 25 }]` then try

```
window.location.href = "checkout.html?OrderId=" + response.data[0].OrderId;
```

Comment: I tried that but getting URL Like this : localhost:56861/public/checkout.html?OrderId=[object%20Object] If i pass response.data in window.location.href = "checkout.html?OrderId ="+response.data –

Answer (score 0):

```
search(search, [paramValue]);
```

This method is `getter / setter`.

Return search part (as object) of current URL when called without any parameter.

Change search part when called with parameter and `return $location`.

```
$location.search({OrderId : 25 });

locationSearchStatus = $location.search();
```

[AngularJs Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)